# Python pdb stops at a line without a breakpoint

Tags: python, pdb

I ran the following code in JupyterLab:

```py
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
def cute_function(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    c = 7
    m = 1
    d = 1
    k = 2
    l = 10
    p = 7
    for i in range(n):
#         breakpoint()
        print(a,b,c,d)
        a = a + 1
        b = b + b
        x = k / d
        x = d + x
        d = x / k
        c = m * l
        m = c % p
        c = c // p
    return (a,b,c,d)
        
cute_function(10) 
cute_function(100)
```

and then I debugged interactively:

```
--Return--
None
> <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>(1)<module>()
----> 1 import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
      2 def cute_function(n):
      3     a = 0
      4     b = 1
      5     c = 7

ipdb>  b 13
Breakpoint 1 at <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>:13
ipdb>  c
> <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>(13)cute_function()
     11     for i in range(n):
     12 #         breakpoint()
1--> 13         print(a,b,c,d)
     14         a = a + 1
     15         b = b + b

ipdb>  display a
display a: 0
ipdb>  b cute_function
Breakpoint 2 at <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>:2
ipdb>  c
0 1 7 1
> <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>(14)cute_function()
     12 #         breakpoint()
1    13         print(a,b,c,d)
---> 14         a = a + 1
     15         b = b + b
     16         x = k / d

ipdb>  undisplay a
ipdb>  b
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>:13
    breakpoint already hit 1 time
2   breakpoint   keep yes   at <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>:2
    breakpoint already hit 1 time
ipdb>  c
> <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>(13)cute_function()
     11     for i in range(n):
     12 #         breakpoint()
1--> 13         print(a,b,c,d)
     14         a = a + 1
     15         b = b + b

ipdb>  c
1 2 1 1.5
> <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>(14)cute_function()
     12 #         breakpoint()
1    13         print(a,b,c,d)
---> 14         a = a + 1
     15         b = b + b
     16         x = k / d

ipdb>  c
> <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>(13)cute_function()
     11     for i in range(n):
     12 #         breakpoint()
1--> 13         print(a,b,c,d)
     14         a = a + 1
     15         b = b + b

ipdb>  c
2 4 4 1.4166666666666665
> <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>(14)cute_function()
     12 #         breakpoint()
1    13         print(a,b,c,d)
---> 14         a = a + 1
     15         b = b + b
     16         x = k / d

ipdb>  b
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>:13
    breakpoint already hit 3 times
2   breakpoint   keep yes   at <ipython-input-1-d9984dfe3110>:2
    breakpoint already hit 3 times
ipdb>
```

To my surprise, the code always stopped at line 14, even if there's no breakpoints. It seemed as if the breakpoint 2 was moved to line 14, because the hit count kept increasing.

It seemed to me that this was caused by the "display" command, because removing the display command solved the problem.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

My Python version is 3.9.4, and my JupyterLab version is 3.0.14. I use MacBook Pro 2017, macOS Big Sur v11.4.

**Edit:** this also happens when I use default python 3.7.0 IDLE, so this has nothing to do with JupyterLab.

Comment: I was about to teach one of my friend how to use pdb, so I wrote this obscure function. But then I ran into this bug. The inner loop increments a, doubles b, assigns the next digit of 5/7 to c, and gives a better approximation of sqrt(2) to d per iteration.

Comment: By display command do you mean print?

Comment: @krassowski I mean the pdb debugger command. To quote the docs: display [expression]: Display the value of the expression if it changed, each time execution stops in the current frame. Without expression, list all display expressions for the current frame. New in version 3.2. See [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) for detail

Comment: This looks to me exactly what display is supposed to do, this is set a dynamic breakpoint on matching expressions, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-display

Comment: @krassowski Thank you for noting that. However I `undisplay a` several lines after, yet the breakpoint persists.

Comment: Here's my debug commands: `b 13;;c;;display a;;b cute_function;;c;;undisplay a;;b;;c;;c;;c;;c;;b`